# How to call '[object Object] in angular *ngFor

Tags: node.js, json, angular

myjson is :

```
[
  {
    "support": 2,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Segitiga Wolfis",
          "price": 23000,
          "description": "Bahan seratus persen ori, kain kualitas premium. Cocok untuk berpergian acara dan bersantai. Dibuat dengan sepenuh hati dengan prporsisi jahit yang detail dan hasil tampilan yang unik.",
          "image": "https://cf.shopee.co.id/file/a98a024dfd6e210773bce8af3e8f604d_tn"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 1,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Instan Hijab Triangle",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan Lembut, Cocok untuk berpergian dan bersantai. Instant Hijab Triangle Veil Instant Triangle Lace Veil Amelia Lace Triangle\r\n\r\nColor: Amelia Softpink, Amelia Softpeach, Amelia Navy, Amelia Black\r\nType: instant triangle hijab\r\nMaterial: pollycatton\r\nWeight: 120 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/025c74dc748fb1ebc76e95d7be7f85b2.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i",
          "price": 44000,
          "description": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i Diamond Hijab Quadrilateral\r\n\r\nIngredients = Italiano Diamond\r\n\r\nSize = 145 x 145 cm\r\n\r\nEdges = boutique-style sewing edges\r\n\r\nWeight = 210 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/87fcc99a88694bbdcf36841e7671a5cd.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 1,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Instan Hijab Triangle",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan Lembut, Cocok untuk berpergian dan bersantai. Instant Hijab Triangle Veil Instant Triangle Lace Veil Amelia Lace Triangle\r\n\r\nColor: Amelia Softpink, Amelia Softpeach, Amelia Navy, Amelia Black\r\nType: instant triangle hijab\r\nMaterial: pollycatton\r\nWeight: 120 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/025c74dc748fb1ebc76e95d7be7f85b2.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Pashmina Ceruti Starp",
          "price": 50000,
          "description": "Pashmina Ceruty strap Pasmina Babydoll Ceruty hijab pasmina strap\r\nkarakteristik bahan :\r\n- Lentur/jatuh kebawah sehingga mudah dibentuk.\r\n- Tekstur ringan, halus dan lembut. nyaman untuk dipakai sehari hari.\r\n- Tidak mudah kusut.\r\n\r\nMaterial = Babydoll ceruty\r\nSize = 175 x 75 cm\r\nEdge = neat sewing\r\n\r\nWeight = 120 grams\r\n",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/9b7d781d5c2c1bbb73ba7d5615b7677f.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Satin Square",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan hijab satin sangat baik dan berkualitas. Terlihat mengilap dan lembut, serta ringan saat disentuh. Ketika dikenakan hijab ini nyaman dan tak membuat rasa panas. Untuk kamu yang suka dengan tampilan berbeda, andalkan saja hijab satin ini yang cocok untuk gaya kasual hingga kondangan.",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/b9ec3e70e56c34c97cc578bc2f027fe2.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 1,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i",
          "price": 44000,
          "description": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i Diamond Hijab Quadrilateral\r\n\r\nIngredients = Italiano Diamond\r\n\r\nSize = 145 x 145 cm\r\n\r\nEdges = boutique-style sewing edges\r\n\r\nWeight = 210 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/87fcc99a88694bbdcf36841e7671a5cd.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 1,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Satin Square",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan hijab satin sangat baik dan berkualitas. Terlihat mengilap dan lembut, serta ringan saat disentuh. Ketika dikenakan hijab ini nyaman dan tak membuat rasa panas. Untuk kamu yang suka dengan tampilan berbeda, andalkan saja hijab satin ini yang cocok untuk gaya kasual hingga kondangan.",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/b9ec3e70e56c34c97cc578bc2f027fe2.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 2,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Hijab Instan Diamond Lova",
          "price": 50000,
          "description": "Instant Hijab bergo Lova Instant Hijab Diamond Bergo Lova Instant Khimar Veil no ped\r\n\r\nMaterial = Diamond\r\n\r\n- super neat stitching >> other colors are still in the production process\r\n\r\nWeight = 135 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/e5fa1cb23e7ca49052c5a8a81a534b85.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "support": 1,
    "items": [
      [
        {
          "title": "Instan Hijab Triangle",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan Lembut, Cocok untuk berpergian dan bersantai. Instant Hijab Triangle Veil Instant Triangle Lace Veil Amelia Lace Triangle\r\n\r\nColor: Amelia Softpink, Amelia Softpeach, Amelia Navy, Amelia Black\r\nType: instant triangle hijab\r\nMaterial: pollycatton\r\nWeight: 120 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/025c74dc748fb1ebc76e95d7be7f85b2.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Satin Square",
          "price": 25000,
          "description": "Bahan hijab satin sangat baik dan berkualitas. Terlihat mengilap dan lembut, serta ringan saat disentuh. Ketika dikenakan hijab ini nyaman dan tak membuat rasa panas. Untuk kamu yang suka dengan tampilan berbeda, andalkan saja hijab satin ini yang cocok untuk gaya kasual hingga kondangan.",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/b9ec3e70e56c34c97cc578bc2f027fe2.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Pashmina Ceruti Starp",
          "price": 50000,
          "description": "Pashmina Ceruty strap Pasmina Babydoll Ceruty hijab pasmina strap\r\nkarakteristik bahan :\r\n- Lentur/jatuh kebawah sehingga mudah dibentuk.\r\n- Tekstur ringan, halus dan lembut. nyaman untuk dipakai sehari hari.\r\n- Tidak mudah kusut.\r\n\r\nMaterial = Babydoll ceruty\r\nSize = 175 x 75 cm\r\nEdge = neat sewing\r\n\r\nWeight = 120 grams\r\n",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/9b7d781d5c2c1bbb73ba7d5615b7677f.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Hijab Simple Fat Serration",
          "price": 35000,
          "description": "Khimar simple pet serration / instant veil pet simple serration\r\n\r\nMaterial = Wolvis grade A\r\n\r\nsuper neat stitching >> other colors are still in production process\r\n\r\nWeight = 155 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/00277781e24c7552d21411b3deef11d8.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Pahsmina Baby Doll",
          "price": 35000,
          "description": "Pashmina baby doll ruffle Pashmina ceruty rempel pasmina sabyan kriwil\r\n\r\nMaterial = Ceruty\r\nSize = 75 x 175 cm\r\nEdge = neat sewing\r\n\r\nWeight = 130 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/dd1a41504bf4279a80a1c83922329401-600x600.jpeg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i",
          "price": 44000,
          "description": "Hijab Quadril Syar'i Diamond Hijab Quadrilateral\r\n\r\nIngredients = Italiano Diamond\r\n\r\nSize = 145 x 145 cm\r\n\r\nEdges = boutique-style sewing edges\r\n\r\nWeight = 210 grams",
          "image": "https://www.irvanmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/87fcc99a88694bbdcf36841e7671a5cd.jpeg"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div *ngFor="let i of myjson">
    <h2>support:  {{i.support}}</h2>
      <div *ngFor="let item of support?.items[0]">
           <p>title: {{ item.title }}</p>
           <p>price: {{ item.price }}</p>
           <p>description: {{ item.description }}</p>
           <img [src]="item.image" />
      </div>
</div>
```